# Dynamic concatenated name for textbox in angular

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular5

hi I have a code like the following

```html
<div *ngFor="let phone of phoneList; let phIndx = index;">
 <div class="peoplePhoneTxtDiv">
  <input [disabled]="phone.disabled" class="peoplePhoneTxtBox" type="text" name={{phone.no}}+"phIndx"
[value]="phone.no" [(ngModel)]="phone.no" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to make the texbox name a combination of string + index dynamically. If the texbox name is same, as I change value of one all gets changed. So I tried to do as shown but its an error plz help.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this `name="{{phone.no + phIndx}}"` or `[name]="phone.no + phIndx"`

```
 <div *ngFor="let phone of phoneList; let phIndx = index;">
  <div class="peoplePhoneTxtDiv">
    <input [disabled]="phone.disabled" class="peoplePhoneTxtBox" 
         type="text" name="{{phone.no+phIndx}}"
         [value]="phone.no" [(ngModel)]="phone.no" required>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)